# Highlighting maya commands (such as polySphere) in Eclipse (with PyDev) and EclipseMayaEditor

Tags: python, eclipse, command, highlighting, maya

I have been searching for this but after 2 hours I gave up.

I wanted to work dynamically with another IDE to run maya scripts using Python. So I downloaded **Eclipse** and I installed some plugins: **EclipseMayaEditor** (to connect Eclipse with the script editor in Maya) and **PyDev** (so that I can use the python interpreter in Eclipse).

It works perfectly fine, I can connect the IDE with maya and jump from one to another. BUT I miss a feature I had in Maya's script editor...

Eclipse is not highlighting me the maya commands such as *xform*, *polySphere*, and so on... It is not a big problem but it hurts my eyes a little bit when I stay some hours staring at the screen...

Is there any way to highlight the maya commands or maya nodes or whatever they are called (pardon me for my lack of technical vocabulary)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but the [**Eclipse Maya Editor**](http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/downloads/applications/syntax-scripting/c/eclipse-maya-editor) plugin looks promising. Have you tried it? From the description:

> This is a plugin for Eclipse that turns it into a Maya IDE. As it is
>   Python-centric, it also requires the pyDev plugin. Features include:
>
> - Send the entire contents of an editor to Maya
> - Send a highlighted selection to Maya
> - Python and mel scripts supported
> - Anything done within Maya's own script editor is also echoed in the console view
> - Change the port number of the socket at any time
> - Open up documentation for Maya's Python API, Python Commands,  Pymel, Qt, PySide, PyQt and User options
> - Get results back from Maya in it's own console view
> - Eclipse Helios, Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse Juno supported. Requires PyDev plugin.

---

Reading further though, it looks like it may not do highlighting. From a feature request listed as "pending":

> **Color highlighting on maya python commands**
>   Only maya mel commands get colored, but not maya python commands. The
>   default python functions get highlighted, but not maya’s python
>   commands. I find it useful to avoid typos...

It's possible that request is out of date and it's been implemented since then. You'll have to try it yourself to know for sure. Let us know!

Comment: Hello friend. I work with this wonderful plugin and I cannot see them highlighted. I just have hope for it to be fixes. Otherwise I will switch to pyCharm which this month will release the same level of implementation, and I REALLY LOVE pyCharm INTERFACE for Python scripting... You couldn't imagine it, it's so sweet. I leave you the link so that you can take a look: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/12/announcing-the-pycharm-3-1-eap-opening/ (take a look at the comments section below). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.creativecrash.com/tutorials/using-eclipse-as-a-maya-ide) walks through the steps for getting autocomplete working. While it's not as nice as full syntax highlighting it does give you automatic expansion of function names, fields and methods in Eclipse.

Basically you want to make sure that your interpreter knows the location of the maya python directories and the pypredef folder inside your maya install. Here's shots of my setup.  This is the Libraries tab of my Maya python interpreter:

[image]

and here's the prefedined tab:

[image]

Your paths will of course be relative to where your maya is installed but this should be enough to enable autocomplete.  You'll be able to customize the color scheme in the preferences > themes setting, but I don't know of a way to call out specific imports from other modules in the way the maya editor does.

Comment: Thank you very much theodox. I already had it set up, but I am sure it will be very useful for people who want a nice connectivity Eclipse-Maya and don't have that turned on yet.